# How to set the return value of a function within a mocked dependency in Jest?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to mock a mongoose model so I can unit test an express controller. I've stripped out all of the irrelevant code to show what I'm trying to do. Here is the code to be tested:

```
import User from "../../models/User";

const getAllUsers = async () => {
  const users = await User.find(); // I want to mock the return value of User.find()
  return users;
};

export { getAllUsers };
```

And here is the test file:

```
import { getAllUsers } from "./discord";
import User from "../../models/User";

jest.mock("../../models/User", () => ({
  find: jest.fn(),
}));

describe("getAllUsers", () => {
  test("makes read request to database", async () => {
    User.find.mockResolvedValueOnce("some result"); // Causes error. How can I mock User.find?
    const result = await getAllUsers();
    expect(User.find).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(result).toBe("some result");
  });
});
```

In the test file, User.find is not recognised as a mock. I receive the following test failure:

```
 FAIL  src/controllers/users/discord.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    src/controllers/users/discord.test.ts:10:15 - error TS2339: Property 'mockResolvedValueOnce' does not exist on type '{ (callback?: Callback<(Document<any, any, UserInterface> & UserInterface & { _id: ObjectId; })[]> | undefined): Query<...>; (filter: FilterQuery<...>, callback?: Callback<...> | undefined): Query<...>; (filter: FilterQuery<...>, projection?: any, options?: QueryOptions | ... 1 more ... | undefined, callback?: Callb...'.

    10     User.find.mockResolvedValueOnce("some result");
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.193 s
```

**How can I mock the User `find` method?**

Please note I want to be change the mocked return value of User.find() in each individual test I write. I also want to mock other methods from User, such as findById(), but I have focused on just the find() method for the purpose of writing this post.

EDIT: I have created [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-pond-wzc1z?file=/src/index.test.ts) to make it easier for someone to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like this:

const resultReport = repositoryPort.findById = jest.fn(() => of(mockLoan));

mockLoan is the mock that you wants return.